# Tabulator: wrong cell height with textarea formatter

Tags: javascript, tabulator

In Tabulator 4.9, I'm trying to set up a table with long texts in certain cells. I've used `formatter:"textarea"` for this, but the results are strange. The height of the cells with long text are much too large. See codepen. When I do a manual resize of the column, the cells immediately jump to the correct height. But why is it not the right height in the first place?

https://codepen.io/pen/yLMewyd

```
const longText = "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book."

let exampleData = [
{id:1, name:"Oli Bob", progress:12, gender:"male", col:"red", dob:"19/02/1984", car:1},
{id:2, name:"Mary May", progress:1, gender:"female", col:longText, dob:"14/05/1982", car:true},
{id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", progress:42, gender:"female", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true"},
{id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", progress:100, gender:"male", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
{id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", progress:16, gender:"female", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
{id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", progress:38, gender:"male", col:longText, dob:"12/05/1966", car:1},
{id:7, name:"Jamie Newhart", progress:23, gender:"male", col:"green", dob:"14/05/1985", car:true},
{id:8, name:"Gemma Jane", progress:60, gender:"female", col:"red", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true"},
{id:9, name:"Emily Sykes", progress:42, gender:"female", col:"maroon", dob:"11/11/1970"},
{id:10, name:"James Newman", progress:73, gender:"male", col:"red", dob:"22/03/1998"},
{id:11, name:"Martin Barryman", progress:20, gender:"male", col:"violet", dob:"04/04/2001"},
{id:12, name:"Jenny Green", progress:56, gender:"female", col:"indigo", dob:"12/11/1998", car:true},
{id:13, name:"Alan Francis", progress:90, gender:"male", col:"blue", dob:"07/08/1972", car:true},
{id:14, name:"John Phillips", progress:80, gender:"male", col:"green", dob:"24/09/1950", car:true},
{id:15, name:"Ed White", progress:70, gender:"male", col:"yellow", dob:"19/06/1976"},
{id:16, name:"Paul Branderson", progress:60, gender:"male", col:"orange", dob:"01/01/1982"},
{id:18, name:"Emma Netwon", progress:40, gender:"female", col:"brown", dob:"07/10/1963", car:true},
{id:19, name:"Hannah Farnsworth", progress:30, gender:"female", col:"pink", dob:"11/02/1991"},
{id:20, name:"Victoria Bath", progress:20, gender:"female", col:"purple", dob:"22/03/1986"},
];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data: exampleData,
    headerSort:false,
    columns:[    
        {title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"input", width:150},
        {title:"Progress", field:"progress", formatter:"progress"},
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
        {title:"Multi-line", field:"col", formatter:"textarea"}, //, maxWidth: 350},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", hozAlign:"center"},
        {title:"Driver", field:"car", hozAlign:"center", formatter:"tickCross"}        
    ]
});
```

Comment: There was an issue with the row height calculations in the 4.9 release. if you upgrade to 5.1 it should work correctly

Answer (score 0):

I added a table.redraw(true) after your Tabulator ctor() and got a better result. But at the moment, I couldnt tell you why. Definitely something wrong with the initialization of the columns that is cured by a full redraw; You might want to raise a bug report on GITHub